# XPath select text except some parts

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

How can I write an XPath expression if I want to extract "TEXT 1" but **not** "TEXT 2" and "TEXT 3"?

```
<div class="content">
    <div>
        <p>
TEXT 1 <span class="author"> TEXT 2</span>
     <a href="http://www.example.com" class="more" name="_chf_A_xxlformat_">TEXT 3</a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath will select text nodes that are immediate children of `p`

```
//div[@class='content']/div/p/text()
```

and will therefore exclude "TEXT 2" and "TEXT 3".

You might prefer to eliminate leading and trailing whitespace (and replace repeated internal whitespace, but to no matter here):

```
//div[@class='content']/div/p/text()[normalize-space()]
```

evaluates to "TEXT 1" in both XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
```

You probably did `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`, which takes the current node and convert it recursively to text. `text()` selects only text nodes, excluding child elements and attributes.

Here's a complete XSLT for context:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
        version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
        <xsl:template match="p">
                <out>
                        <xsl:value-of select='text()'/>
                </out>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath:

```
$x("(//div[@class='content']/div/p/text())[1]");
```

Maybe it's not quietely efficient but it seems do its work :)
Note that the [1] will get the first occurrence of a text, if you change text position it will not work properly.

Regards,
Andrea.